# How to find the number of the first block after a specific moment (unix time)?

Tags: mainnet, blocks

I would like to query a range of blocks on the EOSIO mainnet which were created during a specific time span (for example, from unix time 1555500000 to 1555600000, which is around April 17-18, 2019).
How do I find the numbers of the blocks created in that time span?

I see it's possible via getting various blocks with the REST API (`/v1/chain/get_block`), looking at the `timestamp` field of the responses, and performing a binary search for each of my two unix time borders.
Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like dfuse comes to the rescue.

The [`/v0/block_id/by_time`](https://docs.dfuse.io/#rest-get-v0-block_id-by_time) endpoint can be used as follows (example from the link):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    "https://mainnet.eos.dfuse.io/v0/block_id/by_time?time=2019-03-04T10:36:14.5Z&comparator=gte"
```

Have to convert Unix time to ISO8601 extended format, but that can be automated too.

Answer (score 1):

When the blockchain operates normally, you get a new block every half a second. So you can start with any block you want and calculate the diff in seconds times 2 to get the number of blocks to diff from your initial query.

Might be off by just a few since tge real world is not mathematically precise, especially when dealing with time and networks.

Comment: Ideally `0.002*(d.getTime()-1528545389000)` should give the latest block number (considering 1528545389000 is the timestamp when Block1 was generated) But it doesn't. Probably because BPs missed a lot of blocks on the way. So you need a source which knows about when these blocks were missed. You may consider the answer from @Gassa

Comment: d=Date.now() BTW